# How do I read the fuse bits from within my sketch?

Tags: fuses

How can I read the fuse bits from within my sketch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [boot_lock_fuse_bits_get](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__boot.html#ga37ce7078335dd85f04d150a52a01d6ad) function from [<avr/boot.h>](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__boot.html).

```
#include <avr/boot.h>;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(57600);

    cli();
    uint8_t lowBits      = boot_lock_fuse_bits_get(GET_LOW_FUSE_BITS);
    uint8_t highBits     = boot_lock_fuse_bits_get(GET_HIGH_FUSE_BITS);
    uint8_t extendedBits = boot_lock_fuse_bits_get(GET_EXTENDED_FUSE_BITS);
    uint8_t lockBits     = boot_lock_fuse_bits_get(GET_LOCK_BITS);
    sei();

    Serial.print("Low:  0x");
    Serial.println(lowBits, HEX);
    Serial.print("High: 0x");
    Serial.println(highBits, HEX);
    Serial.print("Ext:  0x");
    Serial.println(extendedBits, HEX);
    Serial.print("Lock: 0x");
    Serial.println(lockBits, HEX);
}

void loop() 
{
}
```